# Can I use another player's character save?

Tags: borderlands-2

My PC crashed and when I restarted my Borderlands 2 character was at level 1! (After being level 20)

Is it possible to use someone else's character save?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. Personally I don't like to play with other people's saves because I don't have the feeling that I earned the weapons or that specific level for the game. IF you don't care you can copy someone elses savegame from (default):

win7/vista

`%userprofile%\Documents\my games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\SaveData\`

XP

`%userprofile%\My Documents\my games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\SaveData\`

Mac

`~/Library/Application Support/Borderlands 2/WillowGame/SaveData`

And backup your saves bro!

Answer (score 0):

there are programs like modio for the xbox to change property codes see if you can do the same thing for the computer. Go to the folder with there save copy it and then use a program to save it as your save.